# Bash - Searching Selective Files in a File List

Tags: bash

I have a list of n files, they all have the same names except for the numbers (eg file_1, file_2, file_3... file_n).
However, it is not all these files that interest me, just some, because only some have molecular structures that I need. 
However, within this set of n files, I don't know exactly which ones have the necessary structure (note, each file has only one structure).

What would be the best way to figure out which file has the structure I need? I just need to identify them.
I had thought of making two vectors, one with the names of all files and one with the words that identify the molecules (words that are inside the file can be found with the grep command).

I thought of creating two loops with these two vectors, however, I found problems in this attempt.

```
L='1 2 3 4 5 6 n'

M='molecule1 molecule2 molecule3...'

for l in $L
do
    for m in $M
    do
        echo "$l" >> files.gjf
        grep "$m" file_$l.gjf >> files.gjf
    done
done
```

The problem with these two loops is that I have a very large set of files as well as molecules, so the echo command I use to identify the files I need makes my output very large. A test I performed with a 500 file vector and only 51 molecules generated an output (files.gjf) with 24013 lines.

Can I use another code to do it in a more reliable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure this as follows.  I would use an array to store the keywords you are seeking.

```sh
declare -a a_keywords 
a_keywords="word1 word2 etc"
```

Then I would iterate over the elements in that array:

```sh
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#a_keywords[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
```

then perform a grep on each result:

```
    grep -r "${a_keywords[i]}" /path/to/root/folder/for/your/files/
```

Close your for loop (with `done`).

If you use the above structure to load an array (`declare -a a_keywordsResults`) then you could `grep "${a_keywordsResults[@]}"` using your array of numbers (`declare -a a_keyNumbs`) in a similar `for` loop.

You could reverse this structure (first grep for Numbs and then grep that Results for words) but it will depend on which may be the more efficient for your specific situation.

If you need an output of the final results (those which pass both greps) you could after all of the above pass what's left into a file.

If I've misunderstood your aim, let me know.

Comment: ++ for the suggestion to use arrays. I can't see a way to cram that into my answer so just noting here that I agree that that would be an improvement if indeed there is a need to use separate variables at all. Note that you can loop over the array directly with `for keyword in "${a_keywords[@]}"`

Comment: I was thinking of i because of the following grep where I specifically call that element.  ( grep /path/to/root/folder/for/your/files/ "${a_keywords[i]}" )  Could be grep /path/to/root/folder/for/your/files/ "${a_keywords[keyword]}" I suppose for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can look for multiple strings in one go, and with `-l` can stop searching as soon as it finds the first one in each file and report that file as a match.  So perhaps you are simply looking for

```sh
grep -l -E 'molecule1|molecule2|molecule3|.....' file_1.gjf file_2.gjf file_3.gjf ... >files.gjf
```

If you simply want to search all files matching the wildcard `file_*.gjf` then that's an obvious and easy simplification.

This doesn't let you see which search string exactly was found, though simply removing `-l` will fix that (but then generate more output and print out all the matches with the file name before each match; so, potentially *more* output than your original attempt if there are many matches).

I used the `-E` option to enable a different pattern syntax which makes it easier to specify many search strings in one pattern. You might also want to look into `-f` which lets you put the patterns in a file (and maybe then also `-F` to treat each pattern as a literal string rather than a regular expression).

```sh
printf '%s\n' molecule1 molecule2 molecule3 ... |
grep -Ff - -l file_*.gjf >files.gjf
```

Here, we provide the patterns "file" on standard input (conventionally represented with the pseudo-filename `-` in many Unix commands) instead of storing them in a physical file.  Maybe run the `printf` part in isolation to see what it produces.

As an aside, your nested loops can be made more efficient by moving the redirection after the final `done`. Each `>>` inside the main loop will open the file for writing and seek to the end on every iteration. This is a pretty fast operation on modern computers, but still unnecessary.

```sh
for thing in list of things; do  # really no point in using a variable
    for other in more stuff; do
        echo "$thing"
        grep "$other" "file_$thing"
    done
done >result
```

collects all of the standard output of the outer loop into a single redirect, which simply opens the file once (and avoids the slightly pesky append operation which requires you to separately clear the file if you want to overwrite the results from a previous run).